# Black ops 2 dlcs download and install but doesn't show up

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I am having trouble with my Black Ops 2 map packs that an in-game friend of mine has shared with me. Once that finished installing I went to play them.

Unfortunately, they are no where to be found in the game on Multiplayer or Zombies which is really pissing me off. This only happens with Black Ops 2 even if I purchase the DLCs. I don't know what to do and I need help.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you need to have all the DLC packs in order for it to work properly. We have the same problem when we got the Venegance mappack.
You need to keep turning on and off the DLC in account management.

I have been told though that if you want to find matches and use your DLC content, you must get all map packs.

Apparently somethings wrong with the DL system when you only get one map pack and not the rest...

Hope that helped. I have only just tried figuring it out and this is all m knowledge :)